# Can you log PIC for dual time after you have your PPL?

Tags: faa-regulations, logging

I've looked up a few different regulations (FAA) regarding the logging of time in my logbook and am unclear on how to log my time.

Here's the scenario: I am a private pilot and am getting checked out on a new aircraft. I am sitting in the left seat and am legal to operate the aircraft currency/certificate-wise, but a CFI is taking me through the motions with a new plane. How should I log this? Dual, PIC, or both?

Also, here's scenario two: everything is same as in the above scenario except I am getting checked out on a complex aircraft for my complex endorsement. How should I log this?

Comment: I saw this and was still not 100% clear... the interpretation offered by Lnafziger says "you could log both PIC and dual..." but nowhere in the regs is anything stated about both logging both in the same place. Just trying to cover myself.

Comment: You could also look here - http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12735/must-i-log-aircraft-checkout-flights-as-dual-received?rq=1 - there's so much confusion amongst pilots about logging, and our questions reflect that, sadly.

Comment: In both situations you will log both DUAL and PIC.